# How to get minimum and maximum value by using partition in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
type      value        prod           date
a           20           2          2019-07-08
a           20           3          2019-07-08
b           30           2          2019-07-08
b           35           1          2019-07-08
a           40           4          2019-07-09
a           20           4          2019-07-09
b           32           3          2019-07-09
b           31           3          2019-07-09
b           30           2          2019-07-09
b           33           2          2019-07-09
b           12           1          2019-07-10
b           23           1          2019-07-10
b           20           2          2019-07-10
b           22           2          2019-07-10
```

My table looks like this:
First thing, I want to get the result of prod / value as util for each type and also date, but for every result I need to also sum from the previous dates.

By that, I also need to know the minimum and the maximum value from each type and also date.

What I have done so far:

```
select *, t1.value / t1.prod as util
select
   type, date, sum(value), sum(prod)
from table1
where true
   and event_date <= ‘2019-07-11’
group by type, date) t1
```

How can I get the minimum and the maximum util by the logic I have that the util calculation should be sum from the previous dates. I assume I need to use `partition`, but I am still not sure for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results. Your explanation is quite hard to follow as well, and it is not helped by having a query that is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are looking for this. It gives you min, max, sum values of `value` column by ordering by `date` and partitioning by `type`.

Check this:

```
drop table tmp_table10
create table tmp_table10
(

type nvarchar(5) null,
value float null,
prod nvarchar(255) null,
date nvarchar(255) null,

)

insert into tmp_table10

values('a',           '20'           ,2          , '2019-07-08'),
('a',           '20'           ,3          , '2019-07-08'),
('b',           '30'           ,2          , '2019-07-08'),
('b',           '35'           ,1          , '2019-07-08'),
('a',           '40'           ,4          , '2019-07-09'),
('a',           '20'           ,4          , '2019-07-09'),
('b',           '32'           ,3          , '2019-07-09'),
('b',           '31'           ,3          , '2019-07-09'),
('b',           '30'           ,2          , '2019-07-09'),
('b',           '33'           ,2          , '2019-07-09'),
('b',           '12'           ,1          , '2019-07-10'),
('b',           '23'           ,1          , '2019-07-10'),
('b',           '20'           ,2          , '2019-07-10'),
('b',           '22'           ,2          , '2019-07-10')


select
    *
,   max(value) over(partition by type order by date) maxValueByType
,   min(value) over(partition by type order by date) minValueByType
,   sum(value) over(partition by type order by date) sumValue

from tmp_table10
order by type, date
```

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question as you want the cumulative min and max of `util` which is calculated like this:

```
select type, date, sum(value) / sum(prod) as util
from table1
where event_date <= ‘2019-07-11’
group by type, date;
```

Then you can use window functions:

```
select type, date, sum(value) / sum(prod) as util,
       min(sum(value) / sum(prod)) over (partition by type order by date) as min_running_util,
       max(sum(value) / sum(prod)) over (partition by type order by date) as max_running_util
from table1
where event_date <= ‘2019-07-11’
group by type, date;
```